# remove unused folder and copy needed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to remove all Folder with

```
rm -R !(foo|bar|abc)
```

exclude the given folder names, that could be two or more.

That works fine!

In the next step I need to copy the needed missing folder from another direction in this folder.

I tried following, but it doesn't work, and it should also be flexible with folder counts.

```
rm -R !($neededfolders)
ownedfolders=$(ls ./dest/)    #
find ../source/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep "$neededfolders" | grep -v "$ownedfolders" | xargs cp -Rt ./dest/
```

My problem with the code is that grep won't use multiple names, I also tried to declare the ownedfolder, set the second grep to

```
grep -v ${ownedfolder[i]}
```

and put the whole thing in a for loop, but these ends in a fallacy.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
 needed='@(foo|bar|abc)'
 for dir in ../source/*/ ; do
     dir=${dir%/}
     if [[ $dir == ../source/$needed && ! -d dest/${dir##*/} ]] ; then
         cp -R "$dir" dest/
     fi
done
```

This avoids the ugly variable `$ownedfolders` populated by the output of `ls`.

Comment: can I use  needed='@$(examplevariable)' ?

Comment: @Mario if the value of `$examplevariable` was `foo|bar|abc`, I guess you could use `needed="@($examplevariable)"` or (slightly more paranoid) `needed='@('"$examplevariable"')'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-E` option to `grep` to enable extended regular expressions, which recognize `|` alternatives:

```
find ../source/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -E "$neededfolders" | grep -v -E "$ownedfolders" | xargs cp -Rt ./dest/
```

Comment: The validity of this approach is completely dependent on the folder names begin "well-behaved", which is something that is at least worth mentioning If you're recommending it.

Comment: thanks for resolution, but my variable $neededfolder is "foo|bar|abc" but the variable $ownedfolder looks like "foo  bar" it has 2 spaces in between and no pipe.

Comment: How do you want that to be used? You want to filter out `foo` and `bar`? You need to change it to a real regular expression, by replacing the spaces with pipes.